# Database normalization: Table design smells

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, normalization

The way a part of my database is designed I have three tables:

#### Partners

- PartnerId

#### XYZPrograms

- XYZProgramId

#### PartnerXYZPrograms

- PartnerId
- XYZProgramId

Each Partner can have **zero or one** XYZProgram. The PartnerXYZPrograms table relates the partner with a XYZProgram. So I have the following relationships/constraints in PartnerXYZPrograms table:

`PartnerId` and `XYZProgramId` are foreign keys; `PartnerId` is unique and also the `XYZProgramId` is unique.

Now this seems to smell. I am getting back to DB design after 6 years so I can't immediately say what rule of normalization this is breaking but I suspect it is breaking something. PartnerXYZPrograms table is most likely redundant and XYZPrograms table should probably contain the PartnerId.

So my question is what are the **smells** when designing tables that suggest database normalization is likely screwed up.

Comment: Your example is a textbook many-to-many design - there is no "smell".  Both columns in `PartnerXYZPrograms` should be the primary key...

Comment: Can a single program be related to more than one partner? If so, then that's a standard many-to-many relationship as OMG Ponies says.

Comment: Are you sure its a many to many design? There can be zero or one programs for each partner.

Comment: Each partner has a unique program or none at all.

Comment: @OMG Ponies. It should be but it can't be which sort of 'smells'.

Comment: Regardless of the specifics of this example, I think database smells are a very reliable tool to guide design decisions (or even better database re-factoring). They are worth talking about.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Because my answer to Tom H.'s question is in the negative.

Comment: @NVM: Then you want a one-to-many, which means getting rid of the `PartnerXYZPrograms` & adding a `XYZProgramId` column to the `PARTNERS` table.  Still, no smell...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Why no smell sir?!? I want a one to zero-one relationship. Which should mean adding PartnerID to XYZPrograms table. The way I had it setup I had a table which related two Id from two tables but could not create a composite key of the two ID's but each ID column could serve as a primary key. This immediately gives a hint that the table is redundant. If this is not a smell I don't know what is?

Comment: @NVM: I'm not up on the lingo, but the design in this case is automatic to me so I don't see how there's a "smell".

Comment: @OMG Ponies. Let me put it another way. What things create a red flag when you refactor a database design?

Comment: @NVM: Any database I didn't architect myself =)  I'm currently working on performance improvements for a database that had "table-itis" - doesn't matter how similar, each aspect had to have its own table... I cringe for all the UNIONs I see daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to spot these smells is to visualize how the dataset will look when active. The obvious and most fundamental smells that relate to normalization:

- A table has the same redundant data in a column, the values of which are not keys (or part of a composite key) to another table. This one should set off an alarm bell. If you have an entity called Job Listing and one of the columns "Category" contains values like "Management", "Management", "Engineering", "Management", this should immediately tell you that there is an additional concept worth representing.

  - A table has redundant data in a column that is sometimes populated similar to the previous smell and sometimes null. This seems a bit like the one above, but there is a distinction. This means that there is a separate idea that needs to be represented, but it is part of a composition relationship. Ex. Employee entity called ManagerInfoID that has a key to a record in the manager table with some info. It is null for all non managers. (I've seen this one more often than I would have liked.
  - Another possible smell is a Merge Table that just doesn't look right. More often than not, people gravitate a link or merge table (like ManagerEmployee) by default. While this is in fact an optimal solution to dealing with many to many relationships, sometimes complicated relationships like the one you noted above have characteristics that just don't seem right in a merge table. The better (perhaps?) solution is to model the zero to many or one to many relationship similar to what you have mentioned above (by putting the PartnerId in the XYZPrograms table).

In my honest opinion, I think that forgetting normalization rules and sticking to smells is a really good thing. It prevents things like #3 from happening, where a chaotic struggle to conjure up rules from a class you barely remember years ago usually results in a theory/practice mismatch and has you applying principles wrong.

The good thing about relational databases is that your data looks really ugly when you see it if it hasn't been modeled properly. This is something that comes from getting bit by de-normalized databases (or worse having to clean up the aftermath).

What other smells can you think of?